# Java console calculator with user-defined variables

Tags: java, algorithm, calculator

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now, I'm trying to implement a java calculator program that will evaluate math expressions from the console. The difficulty is, this program must also accept user-defined variables from the console with the keyword: "define", and then evaluate them as well. 

For example, a user types 
"(define i = 3) + 4 * 2" 
into the console, the program will recognize the keyword "define", and evaluate the expression as 
3+4*2 = 11. 

The main problem is I don't know how to approach this problem since the hierarchy could get very complex,  especially when you have something like this: 
"(define i =(define j =( define k = 5)+7)+3) -k". 
In this case, k = 5, j = k+7 = 12, i = j+3 = 15, so result = i-k = 10(calculator returns this value).
You could also define/redefine the same variable in one expression, like this:
(define i = (define i = 1)+1) - (define i = 1)
Here, i will first be = 1, then i = i + 1 = 2, then i will be redefined to 1, so the whole expression evaluates to 1+1-1=1.
Any unbalanced parentheses, variables without a define statement will be recognized as error.

My approach: 
First convert the expression to a regular math expression, that is, replacing all the user-defined variables with their corresponding values, then evaluate the whole expression. But even this is difficult when you have nest define statements. To complete this "replacement process", I've tried the following:

Step 1. Use regex to match a expression like "let [a-zA-z]+ = [0-9]+", which corresponds to "the variable that has a actual value instead of a reference", so if I have "(define i =(define j =( define k = 5)+7)+3) -k", my program would try to find "k = 5".

Step 2. Then, store k=5 in a hashmap, then replace all the "k" with value 5, so the expression would now look like "(define i =(define j =(5)+7)+3) -5". This way, recursively, I'm hoping to get rid of all letters so the expression can be evaluated.

As you can tell, my approach doesn't work when the user redefines a certain variable, and it doesn't check if we have any unbalanced parentheses.

So I'm wondering if my approach is actually viable, or is there a better way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Horrible formatting. Impossible to read.

Comment: I vaguely recall classes about _compiler construction_ at uni, and - with all respect - I think your approaches are both too naive. The problem sounds like it's best tackled with a good book about compiler & language theory...

Comment: Look at writing a [Parser.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem is rather complex, the approach I'd offer is to handle the parenthetical expressions first. In fact, the goal is to process the information in the agreed order. In elementary school, we learned about PEMDAS (parentheses, exponents, multiplication/division, addition/subtraction).

You've added a new (unary) operator called define. Since its your code, you should choose its importance within the operation heirarchy. Perhaps its always parenthetical? Furthermore, note that you are giving a left to right importance as well.

In any case, it would be easier to parse a mathematical expression if every operator were binary. So you can fake it.

First, parse an expression into an array. For example, the expression

```
(define i = (define j = ( define k = 5) + 7) + 3) -k
```

would become

```
[ ( , 0 , define i, (, 0, define j, (, 0, define k, 5, ), +, 7, ), -, k ]
```

Then you would go through and evaluate.

Consider first accomplishing this relevant problem from LeetCode Online Judge: https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/